# Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured error

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, kubernetes

I view the logs of the pod: kubectl logs backend-deployment-678976d485-hl8nl

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-12-18T22:07:58.768Z ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

Action:

Consider the following:
If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).

This is my application.yaml:

```
server:
  port: 8080

spring:
  datasource:
    #url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/ticketdb
    url: jdbc:postgresql://postgres-service:5432/ticketdb
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    username: postgres
    password: postgres
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
        format_sql: true
    show_sql: true
  mail:
    host: smtp-mail.outlook.com
    port: 587
    username: EzTicket_supp@outlook.com
    password: Parola1234
    properties:
      mail:
        smtp:
          auth: true
          starttls:
            enable: true
```

This is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.6.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.mail</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.5</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <image>
                        <builder>paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-base:latest</builder>
                    </image>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>org.example.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

    </build>

</project>
```

I make deploy my backend like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: backend-service
  namespace: c114c-ticketing
spec:
  selector:
    app: backend
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
  type: ClusterIP
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: backend-deployment
  namespace: c114c-ticketing
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: backend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: backend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: backend
        image: vladone2011/backend-image:latest 
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

And I deploy my postgres like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: postgres-deployment
  namespace: c114c-ticketing
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: postgres
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgres
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: postgres
        image: postgres:latest
        env:
        - name: POSTGRES_DB
          value: ticketdb
        - name: POSTGRES_USER
          value: postgres
        - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
          value: postgres
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5432
        volumeMounts:
        - name: postgres-storage
          mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
      volumes:
      - name: postgres-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: postgres-pvc
```

this is the postgres-service.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: postgres-service
  namespace: c114c-ticketing
spec:
  selector:
    app: postgres
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 5432
      targetPort: 5432
```